# can't run vue.js projects which i downloaded in visual studio code and getting this: ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

I restarted my computer and reinstalled everything and I don't have a problem creating a Vue project and using the **npm run serve** command, but when I want to run the projects I archived, I get this error:

```
npm ERR! Missing script: "serve"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\evinm\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-04-07T08_00_56_626Z-debug-0.log
```

For those who get the same error as me, I tried the suggested solutions here but it didn't work for me. I need your help friends.
*NOTE: these archived projects all work without error*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run this command cd 'your-project-name' not youre global folder after that use npm run dev it works for me.

Comment: Please, consider adding the command example, like:
`cd your-project-name`

Comment: It helped thank you! i was  in the wrong directory. Now it works with "npm run serve".